# Can I run Ubuntu on two different machines from the same drive?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, multiple-workstations

Recently I lost an AMD graphics card and replaced it with a newer Nvidia. After some fun and games I managed to get everything working (at home) as it should.

Occasionally however I take the SSD that has Ubuntu on it to work, both machines have a hot swap drive to make this easy.

The work machine has Intel onboard graphics and when I load Ubuntu on this machine it just keeps bouncing back to the login screen. Is there any way to easily switch the graphics setup based on the machine being used?

Comment: Ubuntu itself it's easily swappable : I've two laptops and swapped the same SSD between them multiple times without issues.  The issue with the login screen may be related to the graphics card, but if it did then it wouldn't load the login screen in the first place.

Comment: @Serg I'll have a poke around in the logs. I'm assuming syslog for login failure, or should I try elsewhere?

Comment: Xorg and lightdm logs in /var/log  might help. Also,  try checking for permissions on the `~/.Xauthority` file . It is typical issue when user is kicked back to login screen if that file is root owned

Comment: Also , it's just a speculation, but the nvidia and intel modules could be conflicting (?). I'll need to ask someone to verify this

Comment: What you are trying to do will not work, because you most probably have the proprietary NVIDIA drivers installed. You would have to uninstall them before plugging the SSD into the work machine and reinstall the drivers before booting the system on your home machine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't it be possible to install Ubuntu on both computers and configure both to use a third drive for the */home* dir? The only pain would be to maintain software packages on both systems, as in installing and updating everything twice.

Comment: @potAito I'd considered two things. One doing similar to above but just partitioning the same drive and configuring grub to provide options for each. I'm assuming this would be achievable, I'm fairly new to Ubuntu. The other was buying a cheap nvidia card and just sticking that in the work PC. I'm more inclined to do former as I won't be out of pocket and it's more likely to work on other machines too.